# Strange UIImage positioning problem

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimage

I created a view in Interface Builder with a bunch of labels and an image.  When I pushed the view onto a UINavigationController, it worked perfectly.  I then inserted the view into a UITableView as a cell (instead); in order to do so, I had to convert change the superclass of its view controller from a UIViewController to a UITableViewCell.  However, when the view is displayed inside the table its labels are all positioned correctly but the image is displayed at its original (un-resized) size in the center left of the screen.  I cannot seem to change its size or position no matter what I do.  Please let me know if you have any idea what the problem might be, as I am completely stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.  UITableViewCell has its own imageView property, which was conflicting with the IBOutlet imageView property in my subclass.  I simply had to rename the property in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `contentMode` of the view that contains the image to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`, `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`.